# PL/SQL Group By question adding extra columns dependent on row numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm struggling with a group by. I have a query which pulls two rows of data for some stock that has been counted. The rows it returns are like this.

[image]

However, I need this to display on one row like below.

[image]

This example only has two counts taking place but other examples could have up to 4 rows so would potentially need a Count 3 and Count 4 column. The count difference needs to be the last count quantity - the first rows original quantity. There is a dstamp field which can be used to identify when each count happened.

My current SQL I'm using to pull this data is below

```
Select bin, sku, original_qty, (original_qty + count_qty) countQty, count_difference, quantity, counter
FROM stock_counts
order by bin, dstamp DESC
```

Comment: How do you know which `count` value goes in `count1` vs `count2` or `count4`?  Is there some column of the `stock_counts` table that provides an order?  A date perhaps?

Comment: My apologies, yes I have a dstamp field. the lets me know which count if first.

Comment: OK.  And how do you know which row's `original_qty`, `countdifference` and `counted_by` to display?  It looks like you're taking the `original_qty` from one row and the `countdifference` from another.  I'm guessing that you're grouping the rows by `bin` and `sku`?

Comment: Yeah so I want to group by bin and sku, then the original quantity to be the original quantity value from the first row, then count difference to be the count from the second row - the original quantity.

Comment: OK.   So `countdifference` comes from the second row even if there are 4 rows?  And where does `counted_by` come from?

Comment: Hi sorry, countdifference needs to be the final count - the original quantity. So if 4 rows then it would be count 4. The counted_by just needs to be the last person to count it so from that last row.

Comment: @JustinCave I've edited the question so I'm hoping it's clearer what I'm attempting to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not even returning `dstamp` in the results. But if you want to pivot, you can use conditional aggregation.  It is not really clear what all the columns mean.  But you can readily pivot the quantities by time using:

```
select bin, sku,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then countQty end) as original_qty,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then countQty end) as qty1,      
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then countQty end) as qty2,        
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then countQty end) as qty3 
from (select sc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sku, bin order by dstamp) as seqnum
      from stock_counts sc
     ) sc
group by sku, bin;
```

Of course, you need to have enough columns to cover the number of quantities you are concerned about.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! With some tweaking I managed to get it working. Sorry for the badly worded question.